# IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target

Tags: cmake, fmt

I'm getting the following error in cmake

```
[cmake] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "fmt::fmt" configuration
[cmake]   "Debug".
```

I've installed fmtlib

```
$ sudo cmake --install . --config Debug
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libfmt.so.9.1.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libfmt.so.9
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libfmt.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/args.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/chrono.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/color.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/compile.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/core.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/format.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/format-inl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/os.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/ostream.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/printf.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/ranges.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/std.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/fmt/xchar.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/fmt/fmt-targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fmt.pc
```

Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
project (Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(fmt)
target_link_libraries(main fmt::fmt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling without the debug config got it working:

```
$ sudo cmake --install .
```