# How to statically link dozens of .lib files in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a couple dozen .lib files I compiled from Magick++ and I need to add them to CMake. I'm trying to add them like this

```
SET(i "1")
list(APPEND magick_libs_list "")

file(GLOB files ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/lib/release/*.lib)
foreach(filePath ${files})
    list(APPEND targets_list somelib_release_${i})

    add_library(somelib_release_${i} STATIC IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(somelib_release_${i} INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/include)
    set_target_properties(somelib_release_${i} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${filePath})

    MATH(EXPR i "${i}+1")
endforeach()

file(GLOB files ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/lib/debug/*.lib)
foreach(filePath ${files})
    list(APPEND targets_list somelib_debug_${i})

    add_library(somelib_debug_${i} STATIC IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(somelib_debug_${i} INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/include)
    set_target_properties(somelib_debug_${i} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${filePath})

    MATH(EXPR i "${i}+1")
endforeach()

target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets ${magick_libs_list})
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
[path-omitted]\MyApp\src\main.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h': No such file or directory
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
:-1: error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Then I tried to remove the includes outside but then got a linking error.

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/include)
```

```
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
:-1: warning: D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
LIBCMT.lib(initializers.obj):-1: warning: LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Magick::Image::Image(void)" (??0Image@Magick@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (??1Image@Magick@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Magick::Image::read(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?read@Image@Magick@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Magick::Image::write(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?write@Image@Magick@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
MyApp.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
:-1: error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Am I having the wrong approach?

EDIT: fixed the wrong variable name as pointed in the comments, but now I'm getting these errors when trying to build in debug and release mode respectively:

```
CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib(Image.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib(Image.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
# ... and more 500+ similar messages
```

```
CORE_DB_de265_.lib(de265.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
CORE_DB_de265_.lib(de265.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
# ... and more 500+ similar messages
```

So it seems to me both loops are being considered even though I used IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE in one and IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG in the other.

Comment: The problem appears that the runtime selected for ImageMagick does not match the runtime for your application. It appears you are mixing dll release runtime with static release runtime

Comment: @drescherjm I've added those libs to a Visual Studio solution (another project) with /MT and it runs. I did have to change the runtime in CMakeFiles with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")` to avoid a runtime library error.

Comment: In `target_link_libraries` command you use `magick_libs_list` variable, but in `foreach` loops you append to `targets_list` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That solved the error in the OP, but now I'm getting another weirder error. OP updated with new information.

Comment: FYI "OP" means "Original Poster": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean. It is a **person**, not a post. So the sentence "That solved the error in the OP" is not quite correct.

Comment: Your code creates e.g. the target `somelib_release_1` and assigns only property `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE` for it. You link with that target in the Debug build, so CMake will need to choose location of the library suitable for that build type. As far as I know, **by default** if neither `IMPORTED_LOCATION` nor `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` is set for a target, then for Debug configuration CMake emits the **error** like `IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "fmt::fmt" configuration "Debug"` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74587365/imported-location-not-set-for-imported-target).

Comment: ... It smells like your code sets [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) variables, by which you attempt to **suppress** the error from CMake itself. But correct fixing of that error is assigning every pair of IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE and IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG properties for the **same target**. Like you do in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820442). (But different pairs of properties should be assigned for different targets).

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by using ifs: `if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")` `if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")`.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by putting each loop inside a conditional checking the type of build (release or debug):

```
SET(i "1")
list(APPEND magick_libs_list "")

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    file(GLOB files ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/lib/debug/*.lib)
    foreach(filePath ${files})
        list(APPEND magick_libs_list somelib_debug_${i})

        add_library(somelib_debug_${i} STATIC IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(somelib_debug_${i} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${filePath})

        MATH(EXPR i "${i}+1")
    endforeach()
endif()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    file(GLOB files ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/lib/release/*.lib)
    foreach(filePath ${files})
        list(APPEND magick_libs_list somelib_release_${i})

        add_library(somelib_release_${i} STATIC IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(somelib_release_${i} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${filePath})

        MATH(EXPR i "${i}+1")
    endforeach()
endif()

target_link_libraries(ImageConverter PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets ${magick_libs_list})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Magick/include)
```

Comment: Note, that checking for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` doesn't work in case of multiconfiguration [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), like Visual Studio.